# Set column value of tableA to the id of tableB based on date (in tableB)

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two tables. First table is called `employeeinfo` and it looks like this:

```
______________________________________________________________________
| Id | FirstName | LastName | Hours | Rate | TotalCost | BatchDateId |
|____|___________|__________|_______|______|___________|_____________|
| 1  | John      | Smith    |  30   |  40  |   1200    |      ?      |
|____|___________|__________|_______|______|___________|_____________|
| 2  | Jane      | Doe      |  40   | 100  |   4000    |      ?      |
|____|___________|__________|_______|______|___________|_____________|
```

Second table is called `batchdate` and it looks like this:

```
___________________
| Id |    Date    |
|____|____________|
| 1  | 2015-06-25 |
|____|____________|
```

Notice the `"?"` in the first table (`employeeinfo` table).. My goal is to be able to set the `BatchDateId` as the `Id` from the second table (`batchdate` table) based on the date (for example the `2015-06-25`).

BUT the catch also is, Lets say I run the query again tomorrow, I would like it to update the `BatchDateId` with the new `Id` from the `batchdate` table (because it'll have a new row with a new `Id` and a new `Date`).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My statements so far are the following:

```
String employeeInfo = "INSERT INTO employeeinfo (FirstName, LastName, Hours, Rate, TotalCost, BatchDateId) "
                                + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                                + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
                                + "Hours=(?), Rate=(?), TotalCost=(?);";
```

And:

```
String batchDate = "INSERT INTO batchdate (Date) VALUES " 
                + "(?)" 
                + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " 
                + "Date=(?);";
```

EDIT2: So what I'm trying to do is, lets say I've updated John Smith's `Hours` and/or `Rate` **on a different day** (which will also change the `TotalCost`), then the `BatchDateId` should change to the new `Id` which contains the new `Date`. If none of the existing rows in `employeeinfo` are affected **or those rows got updated with in the same day** then the `BatchDateId` stays the same; however if there are new rows then they should have a different `BatchDateId` (Based on the new row in `batchdate` table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you can do a `JOIN` between the tables which will get the matching `Id` and then perform an `UPDATE` operation like below

```
update employeeinfo a
join batchdate b on a.Id = b.Id
set a.BatchDateId = b.Id;
```

Comment: So, how would it fit in with my current statements? That's what I'm confused about.. Like do I insert to `batchdate` table, then insert into `employeeinfo` then do this (what you said)?

Comment: No, what I meant to say is perform an UPDATE only on employeeinfo table directly. no need of INSERT statement.

Comment: So, how would I insert all the other needed values? like the `FirstName`, `LastName`.. etc.  Along with this update?

Comment: Now I am confused; per your post those fields do already have data and you want to update only batchId. So this answer exactly points that.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was trying to show some values on how it looks.. but those values are inserted from my program (see my statements)... Either way if you could look at my EDIT2 in OP maybe it clears up the confusion.